# MVP/MVC naming convention for usercontrols vs forms/windows

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, mvp

I have a desktop application with an MVP architecture.

Most of the views are UserControls and are named with a -View ending, e.g.:

- FoobarView.cs (implements IFoobarView, as used by the presenter)
- FoobazView.cs (implements IFoobazView, ...)

However, some views are actual forms and separate windows:

- QuuxWindow.cs (implements IQuuxView).

I think this naming convention is misleading.  I'd rather call it QuuxView.cs, however I'd also like to make it obvious that it is a Form, not a UserControl like the rest.

I was thinking of QuuxWindowView.cs, which would implement IQuuxView (or even IQuuxWindowView), but it's a bit confusing, and I'd like to find out what is the common naming convention in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use I[ItemName]View convention for interfaces and [ItemName]Control [ItemName]Form convention for controls and forms. For Presenter there is no difference between control and form.

Comment: Please confirm that you find the following naming convention to be acceptable:   IFoobarView for interfaces, FoobarControl if it's a UserControl, FoobarForm for forms.   That is clear, and I agree with you.   However for the presenters, how about FoobarPresenter. Or a more real life example, using the entity User:   IUserEditView, UserEditForm, and UserEditPresenter.

Comment: We use [ItemName]Presenter and i think that it's normal name convention.

Comment: Great.  I hope someone else finds this post as well in case they are confused. It's always nice to know you are using naming convention that is generally accepted by the MVP community.